# Why cannot I import tfprof_log_pb2 in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

From [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/tfprof/python/tools/tfprof/tfprof_logger.py#L30) I get to know that the new added profile tool is imported, but it seems strange: 1) it cannot be imported from the interactive interface; 2) and when running the mnist example in spyder I also get an error sayinng `ImportError: cannot import name 'tfprof_log_pb2'`.

I thought since the tensorflow was instlled in anaconda and then it might be an old version and hence has no tfprof in it. But this would only explain why I cannot run `from tensorflow.tools.tfprof import tfprof_log_pb2` directly in the interactive interface(not in the anaconda environment) and cannot explain why it raises an error when I run it in anaconda. It raises this error in spyder, then the version which supports tfprof should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `tfprof_log_pb2.py` present on your disk? It is an automatically generated file, and it's not present in the source tree. Instead it's placed in `bazel-genfiles` directory and should've been copied into distribution during build_pip_package.sh

There's [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5014) that fixed some of the missing files for other tools, I wonder if tfprof files escaped the fix (ie, if it's not part of `tools:all_files` target)

BTW, a copy of that file from my local build -- http://pastebin.com/dJnnWKuy

Comment: I know it is generated by the cpp program since all code in that directory in the repository is written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the two answers are right.

In **Ubuntu**(python2.7 and GPU) I take a short cut and updated the tensorflow from 10 to 12 by: 

`pip install \
  -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/ \
  https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

In China I use the mirror in Tsinghua University for much faster installation.
It goes well directly.

But this seems don't apply to **Mac**(at least for python3.5 and cpu only) even if your version of the tensorflow is 12 or above that file has not been generated(even other two files are already listed there(`//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tools/tfprof/`). So I just copied that file(it must be the same as that in my Ubuntu, right?) privided by Yaroslav Bulatov to the folder. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens if protobuf for python is older then 3.1.0 and TF is older too. I had exact problem as below:

$ python

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32)
>>> from tensorflow.tools.tfprof import tfprof_log_pb2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tfprof
```

This is how i solved it:

Updated setuptools to latest 32.x or above version (I did this because my TF install was failing to update setuptools to version 32.x):

```
pip install update --user setuptools
```

After that I installed TF as below:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-py2-none-any.whl
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

You will note that TF 12.1 installs the following:

```
Collecting tensorflow==0.12.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow==0.12.1)
Collecting protobuf>=3.1.0 (from tensorflow==0.12.1)
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==0.12.1)
```

After successful TF Install:

```
Successfully installed protobuf-3.1.0.post1 tensorflow-0.12.1
```

I tried the very first command as below:

$ python

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32)
>>> from tensorflow.tools.tfprof import tfprof_log_pb2
>>> tfprof_log_pb2
<module 'tensorflow.tools.tfprof.tfprof_log_pb2' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tools/tfprof/tfprof_log_pb2.pyc'>
```